# In Snowflake, how do I select directly from a json variable?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I build a select statement in Snowflake where I am selecting directly from a json variant variable, instead of a column in a table?  My json is just an array of objects, and I will want to select the properties as columns. I see tons of examples of using flatten on a variant column, but can't figure out how to select directly from a variable without a table and column.

```
var_input  := '
  [
    {
      "Name": "Avinash Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Father",
     },
    {
      "Name": "Lata Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Mother",
      },
    {
      "Name": "Shrishti Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Sister",
      },
    {
      "Name": "Bobin Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Brother",
      }
  ]' ;
```

Comment: The key step is the `PARSE_JSON()`. The question contains a varchar that is well-formed JSON. `PARSE_JSON()` transforms that varchar into a true JSON Object that can be flattened or accessed using :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly possible, to access variable in `SELECT`. Example below:

```
BEGIN
  LET var_input VARIANT  := 
  '[
    {
      "Name": "Avinash Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Father",
     },
    {
      "Name": "Lata Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Mother",
      },
    {
      "Name": "Shrishti Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Sister",
      },
    {
      "Name": "Bobin Gupta",
      "Relationship": "Brother",
      }
    ]';

   -- materializing the output as temporary table for simplicity
   CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS
   SELECT f.value:Name::TEXT AS name
   FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON(:var_input))) AS f;
END;

SELECT * FROM t;
```

Output:

[image]